# Access command line arguments

Tags: qt, qml, command-line-arguments, qt-quick

I have a Qt app, QML window and a custom class, that is registered with `qmlRegisterType()`, this is basically my `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
   qmlRegisterType<MyType>(...);
   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
   engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/MyType.qml")));
}
```

I have a vital command-line option, that changes the constructor of `MyType`, that's why I want to access command line arguments via QML, I researched a bit and I see two ways so far:

1. Mystical `Qt.Application.arguments`, whose specifications were present in the Qt documentation until Qt 5 had been released. [Link.](https://together.jolla.com/question/31188/qml-argument-access/) 
   I can access `Application.arguments` in my qml file, but what to do with it next? QML engine says it's undefined type, I cannot access it like a list, i. e. `Application.arguments[0]` gives an error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.
2. Get command-line arguments with `QCommandLineParser` and somehow pass it to my custom class, registered with `qmlRegisterType()`. As far as I understand, `MyType`'s constructor is called by QML engine itself, how can I pass the argument to it then?

Comment: `Qt.application.arguments[index]` is the correct way to call the arguments, not `Application.arguments`.  `Component.onCompleted: console.info("Executable: " + Qt.application.arguments[0])` works perfectly fine. Given that you cannot go for option 1? Option two can be viable maybe but not out-of-the-box.

Comment: You are right, args are accessible via `Qt.application.arguments[index]`, I couldn't get it mainly because of the lack of documentation. Qt Creator also does not autocomplete `arguments`, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't you be able to just add the `argv[]` (maybe make it a `QList` first?) using code from [1]?

```
QQuickView view;
view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("currentDateTime", QDateTime::currentDateTime());
view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("MyItem.qml"));
view.show();
```

But, there's an alternative way: You could instantiate `MyType` right there, in your `main` function, and then pass *it* to QML using the above code. Of course, you would have to make `MyType` known to the meta object system, but you've already done that (IIRC) by calling `qmlRegisterType`.

Definitely take a look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html#setting-a-simple-context-property which should give you details on both approaches. You're trying to share information between C++ and QML, which has to be done using Qt APIs.

[1] http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html#setting-a-simple-context-property

Answer (score 1):

If you need access to the arguments inside the constructor of `MyType` then you need to retrieve them there:

```
const QStringList args = QCoreApplication::arguments();
```

Access through QML would be too late, as you can't pass constructor arguments.